# Why is my model not being validated agains data annotations when calling my controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I hav a view model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]+([-._])?)?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\2?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And my action inside my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel model, string button)
```

And my unit test that tests the model data annotaion validation similar as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3353125/504331)

If I test this regex with a name with space (say "Robert Johnson"), it doesn't match.
If I use the same input in my unit tests, an error is raised from and the tests pass (expected behavior)

But when I call the action, the action accepts the data normally. Event if I call ModelState.IsValid, I get a "false" returned.

As far as I know, my action should not be called if the model validation fails. How can I ensure this behavior?

Comment: It would only not be called if client-side validation was active, and the data was invalid.  Otherwise, the data would be POSTed as normal for your action to validate server-side.

Comment: I will look into that tomorrow and let you know if this worked. Tks!

Comment: As a side note, your action will always be called at some point, regardless of whether the data is valid or not.  Remember, client-side validation is there essentially for usability reasons.  Validation should _always_ occur on the server.  Client-side validation is optional; server-side isn't.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thanks for this side note, I will remember that when making the required changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data annotations can be used to validate models on both the client *and* the server.

On the server-side the `DefaultModelBinder` will automatically validate the models that are POSTed to your action methods but it won't prevent invalid models from being POSTed.  It will simply add the error to the `ModelState` and set the `ModelState.IsValid` property to `false` (as you have discovered).  That means you need to check the `ModelState.IsValid` property and redisplay the form with the model if it isn't valid:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel model, string button)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // The model isn't valid.  
        // Redisplay the form with the invalid model.
        return View(model);
    }


    // If we got here it means the model is valid.
}
```

Redisplaying the form with the invalid model will allow any `@Html.ValidationSummary()` or `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)` helper methods to render their validation error messages to the page.

> As far as I know, my action should not be called if the model validation fails.

This is only true if client-side validation is enabled.  You can do this by adding the following *appSettings* to your Web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

... and adding references to the *jquery.validate.js* and *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js* scripts to your view.  This will allow JavaScript to validate the model *before* it is sent to the server and the validation messages will show without a page refresh (much better for the user and your server!).  As @John H pointed out in the question comments, client-side validation is no substitute for server-side validation.  So be sure to leave your server-side validation checks in place.

Comment: Thanks to you and @John H, I've learned a lot with you two guys. I am still missing something to prevent the postback to my action, I will spend some more time re-reading you answer and researching about it. If I fail, I might come back to this question :)

Comment: FYI, I wasn't referencing Jquery. Now it works perfectly. Thanks guys :D