# Unit Test the BindAttribute for method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-binding

I am looking to write unit tests to validate my controller while ensuring that the bind properties are setup correctly. With the following method structure, how can I ensure that only the valid fields are passed from a unit test?

```
public ActionResult AddItem([Bind(Include = "ID, Name, Foo, Bar")] ItemViewModel itemData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save and redirect
    }

    // Set Error Messages
    // Rebuild object drop downs, etc.
    itemData.AllowedFooValues = new List<Foo>();
    return View(itemData);
}
```

Broader Explanation:
Many of our models have lists of allowed values that we don't want to send back and forth, so we rebuild them when the (ModelState.IsValid == false). In order to ensure these all work, we want to put unit tests in place to assert that the list was rebuilt, but without clearing the list before calling the method, the test is invalid.

We are using the helper method from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3353125/1439998) for ensuring the model is validated, and then our unit test is something like this.

```
    public void MyTest()
    {
        MyController controller = new MyController();

        ActionResult result = controller.AddItem();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        ViewResult viewResult = result as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
        ItemViewModel itemData = viewResult.Model as ItemViewModel;
        Assert.IsNotNull(recipe);
        // Validate model, will fail due to null name
        controller.ValidateViewModel<ItemViewModel, MyController>(itemData);

        // Call controller action
        result = controller.AddItem(itemData);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        viewResult = result as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
        itemData = viewResult.Model as ItemViewModel;
        // Ensure list was rebuilt
        Assert.IsNotNull(itemData.AllowedFooValues);
    }
```

Any assistance or pointers in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for.  Are you looking for a way to detect that the Bind Attribute has been used and setup with the correct values on your controller (ID,Foo...)? Or are you looking for a way to test that the MVC runtime uses the attribute correctly?  Or a way to manually apply the attribute to your test model to recreate the behaviour of the MVC runtime, so you can test your methods?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: I am looking for a way to test that the bind attribute is applied, so that if a model has fields that are not declared for binding, the values are not passed from the test to the controller the same way that they would not be passed from the view to the controller on a post. 

The end goal is to ensure that all the fields are bound correctly with only bound values being updated on a post to the controller, as well as being able to post a "bad" model (happens for some server validation cases) and have the logic for if (ModelState.IsValid) exercised by a test.

Comment: It's great you got this working.  It's not generally a good idea to edit your solution into your question, since it's effectively an answer, rather than a question.  Can I suggest that you might want to edit it out of your question and post it instead as a self-answer to the question.  It helps to partition the Q & A and as a bonus you might end up with the odd upvote for it.  If you want to keep your solution next to the question when people look at the post, then you can also switch the accepted answer to your post (which I don't have a problem with although other peoples views differ)

Comment: Good thought on the separation. I edited to add mine as an answer, but will leave yours as accepted as it was what got me to my final solution. Thank you so much for the help on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting what you're saying, but it sounds like you want something to ensure that a model you've created in your test is filtered before it is passed to your controller in order to simulate MVC binding and to prevent you accidentally writing a test that passes information to your controller under test that would never actually be populated by the framework.

With this in mind, I've assumed you're only really interested in Bind attributes with the `Include` member set.  In which case you could use something like this:

```
public static void PreBindModel<TViewModel, TController>(this TController controller, 
                                                         TViewModel viewModel, 
                                                         string operationName) {
    foreach (var paramToAction in typeof(TController).GetMethod(operationName).GetParameters()) {
        foreach (var bindAttribute in paramToAction.CustomAttributes.Where(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(BindAttribute))) {
            string properties;
            try {
                properties = bindAttribute.NamedArguments.Where(x => x.MemberName == "Include").First().TypedValue.Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                continue;
            }
            var propertyNames = properties.Split(',');

            var propertiesToReset = typeof(TViewModel).GetProperties().Where(x => propertyNames.Contains(x.Name) == false);

            foreach (var propertyToReset in propertiesToReset) {
                propertyToReset.SetValue(viewModel, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which as it stands would be called from your unit test, before you invoke the controller action like this:

```
controllerToTest.PreBindModel(model, "SomeMethod");
var result = controllerToTest.SomeMethod(model);
```

Essentially, what it does is iterate through each of the parameters that are being passed to a given controller method, looking for bind attributes.  If it finds a bind attribute, then it gets the `Include` list, then it resets every property of the `viewModel` that isn't mentioned in the include list (essentially unbinding it).

The above code may need some tweaking, I don't do much MVC work, so I've made some assumptions about the usage of the attribute and models.

An improved version of the above code, that uses the BindAttribute itself to do the filtering:

```
public static void PreBindModel<TViewModel, TController>(this TController controller, TViewModel viewModel, string operationName) {
    foreach (var paramToAction in typeof(TController).GetMethod(operationName).GetParameters()) {
        foreach (BindAttribute bindAttribute in paramToAction.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {//.Where(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(BindAttribute))) {
            var propertiesToReset = typeof(TViewModel).GetProperties().Where(x => bindAttribute.IsPropertyAllowed(x.Name) == false);

            foreach (var propertyToReset in propertiesToReset) {
                propertyToReset.SetValue(viewModel, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. I was hoping that there was a built in feature in MVC for testing that would allow me to trigger the actual bind code rather than emulate it. Worst case scenario I can go down this path if needed.

Comment: @MartinNoreke I've improved the code a bit to use the BindAttribute to do the filtering, although it still assumes the model is populated then strips out values that shouldn't be there.  I think to get much closer than this with the runtime, you may find you have to start actually invoking the binding logic with a controller context and value provider.  If you don't get what you're after, then you might want to have a dig around the MVC source: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I will start digging into this in a day or two again. I got pulled off on some other work (that never happens :), but I do think that this leads me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the answer provided by Forsvarir, I came up with this as my final implementation. I removed the generics to reduce typing each time it was used, and put this in a base class of my tests. I also had to do some extra work for multiple methods with the same name but different parameters (ex: Get vs. Post) which was solved by the loop of all methods instead of GetMethod.

```
    public static void PreBindModel(Controller controller, ViewModelBase viewModel, string operationName)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = controller.GetType().GetMethods();
        foreach (MethodInfo currentMethod in methods)
        {
            if (currentMethod.Name.Equals(operationName))
            {
                bool foundParamAttribute = false;
                foreach (ParameterInfo paramToAction in currentMethod.GetParameters())
                {
                    object[] attributes = paramToAction.GetCustomAttributes(true);
                    foreach (object currentAttribute in attributes)
                    {
                        BindAttribute bindAttribute = currentAttribute as BindAttribute;
                        if (bindAttribute == null)
                            continue;

                        PropertyInfo[] allProperties = viewModel.GetType().GetProperties();
                        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesToReset =
                            allProperties.Where(x => bindAttribute.IsPropertyAllowed(x.Name) == false);

                        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyToReset in propertiesToReset)
                        {
                            propertyToReset.SetValue(viewModel, null);
                        }

                        foundParamAttribute = true;
                    }
                }

                if (foundParamAttribute)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Overall this became a very clean and easy solution, so now my tests look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    MyController controller = new MyController();

    ActionResult result = controller.MyAddMethod();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    ViewResult viewResult = result as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
    MyDataType myDataObject = viewResult.Model as MyDataType;
    Assert.IsNotNull(myDataObject);
    ValidateViewModel(myController, myDataObject);
    PreBindModel(controller, myDataObject, "MyAddMethod");
    Assert.IsNull(myDataObject.FieldThatShouldBeReset);
    result = controller.MyAddMethod(myDataObject);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    viewResult = result as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
    myDataObject = viewResult.Model as MyDataType;
    Assert.IsNotNull(myDataObject.FieldThatShouldBeReset);
}
```

Just for reference, my ValidateViewModel method is:

```
    public static void ValidateViewModel(BaseAuthorizedController controller, ViewModelBase viewModelToValidate)
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(viewModelToValidate, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(viewModelToValidate, validationContext, validationResults, true);
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```